# CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged fires twice

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, combobox

I have a datagridview with a row that is a combobox and I have a column in that datagridview ("Notes") that I update whenever I change the header, ie whenever I change the value that is in the combobox the field "Notes" is populated by the value for that row and column.

I use the event CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged  to catch that but the problem is that event is fire twice that resulted in a duplication of the values concatenated in the field "Notes".

How can I resolve that.

Example of my code:

```
private void dataGridViewReader_CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {


            string columnName = dataGridViewReader.CurrentCell.OwningColumn.Name;
            dataGridViewReader.CommitEdit(DataGridViewDataErrorContexts.Commit);
            string columnName2 = dataGridViewReader.CurrentCell.Value.ToString();

            if (columnName2 == "Notes")
            {
                for (int rows = 1; rows < dataGridViewReader.Rows.Count; rows++)
                {
                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(dataGridViewReader.Rows[rows].Cells[dataGridViewReader.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex].Value.ToString()))
                    {
                        dataGridViewReader.Rows[rows].Cells[0].Value += dataGridViewReader.Rows[rows].Cells[dataGridViewReader.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex].Value + @"<br/>";
                    }

                }
            }


            DataGridViewComboBoxCell dgvcbc = (DataGridViewComboBoxCell)dataGridViewReader.Rows[0].Cells[dataGridViewReader.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex];
            dgvcbc.Style.ForeColor = Color.DarkGreen;

        }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason of double firing is that cell dirty state turns first ON and then OFF, both cause the consequent changes of cell state.

Here is the solution: add `CellValueChanged` event handler where place your code stuff:

```
private void dataGridViewReader_CellValueChanged(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{                 
    string columnName = dataGridViewReader.CurrentCell.OwningColumn.Name;
    string columnName2 = dataGridViewReader.CurrentCell.Value.ToString();

    if (columnName2 == "Notes")
    {
        for (int rows = 1; rows < dataGridViewReader.Rows.Count; rows++)
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(dataGridViewReader.Rows[rows].Cells[dataGridViewReader.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex].Value.ToString()))
            {
                 dataGridViewReader.Rows[rows].Cells[0].Value += dataGridViewReader.Rows[rows].Cells[dataGridViewReader.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex].Value + @"<br/>";
            }
        }
    }

    DataGridViewComboBoxCell dgvcbc = (DataGridViewComboBoxCell)dataGridViewReader.Rows[0].Cells[dataGridViewReader.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex];
    dgvcbc.Style.ForeColor = Color.DarkGreen;
}
```

And the current `CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged` handler change by the following simple code:

```
private void dataGridViewReader_CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (dataGridViewReader.IsCurrentCellDirty)
        dataGridViewReader.CommitEdit(DataGridViewDataErrorContexts.Commit);
}
```

This should make your essential code run once: when a user makes the cell dirty (when the embedded combobox changes its value).

Comment: Thanks for the help! Works now.

Comment: Ok I found a problem :( Now it's constantly entering in the `dataGridViewReader_CellValueChanged` and never go out...

Comment: Ok I found the problem and a solution: using this `string columnName2 = dataGridView.CurrentCell.EditedFormattedValue.ToString();` instead of `string columnName2 = dataGridViewReader.CurrentCell.Value.ToString();`

Comment: Forget my last comment it's not working either ... Now he saves the last value of the row header and not update the value

Comment: Finally I found the solution. i posted above. Thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution for the problem:

Replace `string columnName2 = dataGridViewReader.CurrentCell.Value.ToString();`
Add: `dataGridViewReader.CommitEdit(DataGridViewDataErrorContexts.Commit);` in the end of the code

New Code:

```
private void dataGridViewReader_CellValueChanged(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{                 
    string columnName = dataGridViewReader.CurrentCell.OwningColumn.Name;
    string columnName2 = dataGridViewReader.CurrentCell.EditedFormattedValue.ToString();

    if (columnName2 == "Notes")
    {
        for (int rows = 1; rows < dataGridViewReader.Rows.Count; rows++)
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(dataGridViewReader.Rows[rows].Cells[dataGridViewReader.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex].Value.ToString()))
            {
                 dataGridViewReader.Rows[rows].Cells[0].Value += dataGridViewReader.Rows[rows].Cells[dataGridViewReader.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex].Value + @"<br/>";
            }
        }
    }

    DataGridViewComboBoxCell dgvcbc = (DataGridViewComboBoxCell)dataGridViewReader.Rows[0].Cells[dataGridViewReader.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex];
    dgvcbc.Style.ForeColor = Color.DarkGreen;

    dataGridViewReader.CommitEdit(DataGridViewDataErrorContexts.Commit);
}
```